# Материалы по Apache Tomcat и Glassfish

Tags: apache, glassfish, java

Стало интересно, что же это такое и с чем его едят.

Подскажите, что почитать, посмотреть, послушать, чтобы понять, что это такое и как этим пользоваться.

Интересует исключительно то, что вы могли бы посоветовать, а не просто список литературы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос не совсем точен... Видимо, вы не сталкивались с ними никогда раньше? Тогда попробуйте прочесть о них основные сведения. Посмотрите официальные [Quick Get Start](http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/quickstart/index.html) и [Glassfish Get Started](http://glassfish.java.net/public/getstarted.html) и видео с него.

Comment: ASP.NET я так понимаю конкурент?

Answer (score 1):

Статьи из вики:

- [Apache_Tomcat](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat)
- [GlassFish](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish)